# Get end date for dataframe having multiple date entries involving more than two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like below for example

```
id  taskname   date
1    task1     25/08/2009
1    task1     26/10/2009
1    task2     
1    task2     12/09/2009
2    task1     25/08/2009
2    task1     25/08/2009
2    task1     12/09/2009
3    task2     
.
.
.
256  task1     17/05/2009
256  task1     21/05/2009
256  task2     20/05/2009
256  task2     25/05/2009
```

In the dataframe, I have two tasks in task name i.e task1 and task2 with multiple ids.
I want endate for individual task name with particular id having multiple date entries.
Some tasks date is left empty and since it's still ongoing and final solution I want enddate to be empty if still ongoing
do ask for clarification if needed.

edit: I have another problem
df look like this,

```
id  taskname   date
1    task1     25/08/2009
1    task1     26/10/2009
1    task1     
    
.
.
.


df.sort_values(by=['id','date'], inplace = True)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["id"],keep ='last')
```

Consider first three rows, if we do sort by ascending order we can get the end date by droping duplicates, but if the date is empty, we can't do that and I want empty one to be displayed as max endate

Comment: Use `df.drop_duplicates(['id','taskname'], keep='last')`

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: @jezrael what to if date entries are not in ascending order?, we can't use keep='last' to get end date.

Comment: Then use `df.groupy(['id','taskname'], as_index=False)['date'].max()`

Comment: @jezrael not working getting " TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float' " inside pandas package files, I corrected groupy to groupby in your code.

Comment: Convert column to datetimes before it.

Comment: @jezrael `df.sort_values(by=['Process ID','End Date'], inplace = True, ascending = False)` I used this logic to that before drop duplicates. I have a problem, if the end date if is empty it will be ongoing, we need to take that instead of max end date. how to do this?

Comment: Is possible change data sample for see problem? Because now working perfrctly, no missing values.

Comment: Maybe help [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I will edit the question please look into that

Comment: Maybe help `na_position` parameter in [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) like `df.sort_values(by=['id','date'], inplace = True, na_position='first')`